# Python Selenium WebElement element = invalid syntax

Tags: python, selenium

I have this python code for Selenium but I have "invalid syntax" highligthing **element** whenever I run it.

```
{
WebElement element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Cancel")
actions builder = ActionChains(driver)
builder.move_to_element(element)
element.perform
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### perform()

[`perform()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.perform) performs all stored actions sequentially.

Additionally, [python](/questions/tagged/python) can initialize and assign data types automatically so you don't have to explicitly mention them.

To invoke `perform()` on the element you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Cancel")
builder = ActionChains(driver)
builder.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

As an alternative, you can use the following line of code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_link_text("Cancel")).perform()
```

Comment: Thanks for that but the code still didn't work. What I'm wondering is the code you gave seems correct but it is still giving an error.